# How do I add a custom network throttling to Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

This is on topic for stackoverflow as it pertains to dev tools.

What I want to do is load a satellite internet profile to F12 Network throttling. Something like 500ms latency & max bandwidth of 25Mbit.

We have some debates as to whether or not our web application can tolerate this due to extensive use of `require.js`.

Answer (score 8):

Based on my reading of the Firefox code, the throttling profiles [are hardcoded](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/597a69c70a5cce6f42f159eb54ad1ef6745f5432/devtools/client/shared/components/throttling/profiles.js), and [not configurable](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/597a69c70a5cce6f42f159eb54ad1ef6745f5432/devtools/client/shared/components/throttling/NetworkThrottlingMenu.js#45). [Bug 1471539](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1471539) (currently open) requests to make them configurable.

In the old times it was possible to edit browser/omni.jar (it's a zip file) and have the changes picked up after a restart. If that's still the case, you could make a separate install of Firefox and edit the hardcoded values (`chrome\devtools\modules\devtools\client\shared\components\throttling\profiles.js` inside the omni.ja)

With appropriate experience, you could extract the code used to [implement](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/597a69c70a5cce6f42f159eb54ad1ef6745f5432/devtools/shared/webconsole/throttle.js#410) [throttling](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/597a69c70a5cce6f42f159eb54ad1ef6745f5432/devtools/server/actors/network-monitor/network-observer.js#827) and run it in the Browser console (in "chrome context"). (At first I suspected the [`network.http.throttle` preferences](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/597a69c70a5cce6f42f159eb54ad1ef6745f5432/modules/libpref/init/all.js#2177) were responsible for this, but that's a completely separate thing related to throttling in background tabs.)

The most sure-fire option is to [make your own build of Firefox](https://docs.firefox-dev.tools/getting-started/build.html), but that requires setting up and a non-trivial amount of system resources.

P.S. How large are your files? If the omni.jar trick doesn't work, it might be easier to select an existing profile and extrapolate.

PPS. You probably have your reasons not to use [WebPack](https://webpack.js.org/) or another bundler, but I have to mention it.

Comment: File size is only a couple of megabytes total, but that latency ... Webpack won't help at all.

Comment: I'm not sure why serving all the code in one (or a few) js files won't help with latency...

Comment: Oh; we used to use a packer that didn't know how to do that.