# Network throttling with Firefox and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

Firefox, like [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/device-mode/), [supports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor/Throttling) network throttling.
But the Geckodriver developers [still haven't added an API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/device-mode/) to manage these network settings ([unlike the Chromedriver developers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46672769))
Although there are `network.http.throttle.*` items in the `about:config` settings, they do not do what we might expect by looking at their name. I checked it by turning on these options, and they did not interfere with watching YouTube with 4K quality.
The same is written about these settings [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57613404).

Are there currently any ways to enable throttling in Firefox using Selenium or is it not possible?

P.S. I tried to add throttling like this and it didn't work:

```py
firefox_profile = FirefoxProfile()
firefox_profile.set_preference("network.http.throttle.enable", True)
firefox_profile.set_preference("network.http.throttle.version", 1)
firefox_profile.set_preference("network.http.throttle.suspend-for", 900)
firefox_profile.set_preference("network.http.throttle.resume-for", 100)
firefox_profile.set_preference("network.http.throttle.hold-time-ms", 800)
firefox_profile.set_preference("network.http.throttle.max-time-ms", 500)

driver = Firefox(
    executable_path=WEBDRIVER_PATH,
    firefox_profile=firefox_profile,
)
```